# how to controll the photo size in flutter splashscreen

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

I need to know how to control the size of the image(gif) on the splash screen
the property is named PhotoSize but there is no decimation  of how to use it

I need the image to be at full width and height

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFzO3.png)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:advika/screens/walkthrough/walkthrough.dart';
import 'package:advika/utils/scale_util.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';

 class Splash extends StatefulWidget {
   static final String path = "/splash";

   @override
   _SplashState createState() => _SplashState();
}

 class _SplashState extends State<Splash> {
  @override
  void initState() {
     super.initState();
     Timer(Duration(seconds: 8), () {
     Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      context, WalkthroughScreen.path, (r) => false);
  });
}

@override`enter code here`
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {`enter code here`

  return Container(

   child: SplashScreen(
     seconds: 8,
     image: new Image.asset(
      'assets/images/loading.gif',
    
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
     ),
     backgroundColor: Colors.black,
     photoSize: 300,
     onClick: () => print("Oops "),
     loaderColor: Colors.white,
    ),
    );
 }
 }
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/splashscreen 
Remember that, this is not best practice , but will save the day I guess!

Answer (score 1):

Let me save you time.

You can use the package that comes with a lot of functions and support for flutter splash screens.

package [link](https://pub.dev/packages/splashscreen)

Below is a sample code I created:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';

class Splash_Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  Splash_Screen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Splash_ScreenState createState() => _Splash_ScreenState();
}

class _Splash_ScreenState extends State<Splash_Screen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SplashScreen(
      seconds: 6,
      navigateAfterSeconds: HomeScreen(), // screen you want to navigate to
      title: new Text(
        'Stack Overflow',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 24.0,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
      image: new Image.asset('assets/images/so.png'),
      loadingText: Text('Loading'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white54,
      styleTextUnderTheLoader: new TextStyle(),
      photoSize: 100.0,
      loaderColor: Colors.blue,
    );
  }
}
```